# Convergence of least square monte carlo

Tags: convergence-divergence, regression, monte-carlo, regression-analysis, stochastic-approximation

I am wondering whether there is any convergence rate of the following approximation and what kind of assumptions shall I impose?

Let $X\in L^2(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^d)$ be a random variable and $g: \mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$ be a given Lipschitz function. Suppose $\{h_k(X)\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is a set of orthogonal basis of $L^2(\Omega;\mathbb{R})$. Let us first consider $h_k$ be indicator functions of disjoint hypercubes in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then I would like to approximate $g(X)$ using a finite number of these basis by setting $g(X)\approx \sum_{k=1}^M a_kh_k(X)$ where $a=\{a_k\}$ solves
$$
a=\arg \min_{b\in\mathbb{R}^M}E[|g(X)-\sum_{k=1}^Mb_kh_k(X)|^2]. \label{a}\tag{1}
$$

Since $a$ may not be able to be computed analytically, I use N independent sample path of $X$ to approximate \eqref{a}, which results in the estimator $\hat{a}$
$$
\hat{a}=\arg \min_{b\in\mathbb{R}^M}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N[|g(X_i)-\sum_{k=1}^Mb_kh_k(X_i)|^2]. \label{b}\tag{2}.
$$

Question:
I would like to know whether there is any convergence rate for $\hat{a}\to a$? What kind of assumptions shall I use?

Or can I show 
$$E[\sum_{k=1}^M\hat{a}_kh_k(X_i)-\sum_{k=1}^Ma_kh_k(X_i)|^2]$$
converges in certain order?

Comment: I think it makes more sense to ask for the convergence of the $\min $ instead of the $\arg\min $.. I'll find you a reference later on that actually shows that convergence

Comment: @Bananach because min actually measures the projection error?

Comment: Yes. Why would you care about having a vastly different set of coefficients, if they produce a very similar function $\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Bananach thanks for your response. I have read the paper. Since the paper contains rich materials, I am not sure I get the result you are referring. May you kindly elaborate more in your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257457982_Quantitative_error_estimates_for_a_least-squares_Monte_Carlo_algorithm_for_American_option_pricing

and let me know if you have questions about it.

EDIT: In particular, check out Equation (25) in Theorem 3.3.

Basically, the error estimate depends on two terms:

The first corresponds to the typical Monte Carlo estimates and roughly behaves like $\sqrt{M/N}$, where $N$ is the number of samples and $M$ is the number of basis functions (in the notation of the paper, $M$ is $\nu-1$. Note that $\nu$ is the VC dimension, but this just equals the number of basis functions minus 1 in your setting)

The second corresponds to how good your basis functions are able to describe $g$. For example, the span of indicator functions of a grid-type decomposition of your domain with mesh size $h$ is able to approximate a Lipschitz function up to an error of size $\mathcal{O}(h)$. (Note that the number of indicator functions used for this is $M=\mathcal{O}(h^{-d})$)

SUMMARY: If you choose the width $h$ of the grid that defines your indicator functions to be $h:=N^{-\alpha}$, then approximately

$$
E[|g(X)-\sum_{k=1}^{M=h^{-d}=N^{\alpha d}}h_{i,h}(X)|^2]\leq \sqrt{M/N}+h=\sqrt{N^{\alpha d-1}}+N^{-\alpha}
$$
To minimize this, you should thus let $\alpha:=1/(d+2)$, which gives you an overall error of $\mathcal{O}(N^{-1/(d+2)})$

Comment: If Inunderstand the paper correctly, you are referring to Theorem 2.2. However, the upper bounded involves the Vapnik–Chervonenkis dimension, however, I am mainly interested in the finite dimensional spaces formed by indicator functions of hypercubes, whose VC dimension I don't know. Second, I am also interested how to moment of $X$ affects the convergence rate, i.e., the plain Monte Carlo method

Comment: @John Added some explanations

Comment: Thanks for your editing. May I know how does the statistical property of $X$ enter the convergence estimate?

Comment: Note that I said "how good your basis functions are able to describe g". This goodness is measured in the $L^2$ norm w.r.t. the induced measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ of $X$. In particular, my example of how indicator functions of boxes within a (bounded!) hypercube are able to approximate Lipschitz funcitons on a (bounded!) hypercube does of course not work when $X$ is not bounded. In other words, if $X$ takes very large values very often, you will need a lot of basis functions to approximate $g$ with a weighted sum of $h_i$ in the $L^2(P^X)$ norm ($P^X$ denoting the induced measure of $X$)

Comment: i understand that part, which basically describes the projection error. But how does the moments of $X$ affects the Monte Carlo simulation of the least square problem? Does it like the classical Monte Carlo?

Comment: No, since you are not approximating $X$ but a function of $X$, namely $g(X)$, and this function $g$ is assumed to be bounded. For example, if $g$ is a constant, and you had only the constant basis function, then you would get the correct coefficient vector, i.e. no error at all, no matter the moments of $X$ (actually no matter how $X$ looks like at all). SUMMARY: Behavior of $X$ is kind of swallowed by $g$

Comment: so let me clarify your point. If I assume $g$ is bounded, no estimate of $X$ will enter the simulation error, which behaves like $\frac{M}{N}$? Since I don't have an access of the paper at the moment, I will check equation (25) for the detailed form of similation error.

Comment: This is correct